# how to add an array of variables to a matrix of variables in Julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I want to implement a column generation algorithm with the JuMP package for Julia. So at each iteration I want to add a multidimensional variable of size `n-1` to another multidimensional variable of size `n`. I know functions like `push!()` and `append!()` do the work with parameters, but I couldn't use them for variables.

Would you please let me know if you know the function or a way to do this?

Comment: I imagine there is a way. Can you post some code or pseudo-code that you *wish* worked. From there I imagine we could point you to a solution

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're trying to do (for example, matrices usually need 2 numbers to specify their size, so I don't even know what a "matrix of size `n`" is). spencerlyon2's suggestion is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question just came up on the julia-opt group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-opt/-QTq4oKsZ9A

In short, you can't append to JuMP's specialized containers, but instead you can use a standard `Vector{Variable}` and `push!` to that.